# Run mypy on all Python files of a project

Tags: python, mypy

How can I run mypy on all .py files in a project? I have seen I can specify a module to run mypy on but not something to specify a file mask or something like this.

Comment: How about just `mypy .` to at least run it on packages?

Comment: This is currently an open feature request: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6385

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If all of your Python files live within a specific module or directory, then just running `mypy folder_name` is fine.

You can also pass in multiple paths if you prefer to target specific files or modules. For example: `mypy a.py b.py some_directory`.

The documentation [has some more details](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#specifying-files-and-directories-to-be-checked) and caveats.

Comment: I must add that for this to work we need to add __init__.py where it is needed in order to make mypy scan a folder as a pakage.

Comment: I tried `some_directory/**/*.py` and that looks recursively, but doesn't include *.py in some_directory.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to check all files, including **not annotated functions**,
you have to specify `--check-untyped-defs` option.

Normally, mypy only checks type-annotated functions
(functions which arguments or return type are type-annotated).

So if you have functions like those,
`mypy .` only shows errors in `foo()`.

```py
# main.py
def foo() -> None:
    print(1 + "a")  # show error

def bar():
    print(1 + "a")  # **DON'T** show error
```

```bash
$ mypy .
main.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

But if you specify `--check-untyped-defs`,
mypy shows all errors even if the functions are not annotated.

```bash
$ mypy --check-untyped-defs .
main.py:2: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
main.py:6: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "str")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Official documentation:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code